# Defining test case meta data on SOAP UI test cases

Tags: soapui

Is there a way to define meta data on Soap UI test cases. like Jira id, test case Id, Description, author and etc. I need this information in order to publish to a confluence page along with the test results. Thanks.

[sample report format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABq9W.png)

Comment: Unclear question. Soapui allows you to have test case name, description already.

Comment: When Generating the Test report I need to have things like Jira Id, user Id, and test case Id associated with the test case. In Junit we can annotate test methods with custom annotation like "@Jira" "@StoryId" and etc and process them when generating the test report. But I couldn't find a way to do the same in SoapUI.

Comment: Well, how are you currently generating the report? any screen shot?

Comment: Currently I am depending on the maven-surefire plugin to generate the report. report looks like below http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/images/surefire-sample1.PNG . But we are trying to write a new maven plugin which will have following format testcase name| Jira Story | status | Author | stack trace|

Comment: Ok, then were do you want to change the data from the given report? a mock wire-frame?

Comment: I have add the sample report format in the Question.

Comment: Well that appears entirely different from surefire reports. I am no voice maven. But if you want to just have the data for each test case, there are pre-built features for desc and name of the test case. You can leverage custom properties and access when you them.

Comment: Thanks @Rao I think that answers my question. I will define those data in custome properties (In the test case scope) and use them in my new reporting plugin.

Comment: Added the same as answer so that it can be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI allows to provide name and descriptions by default. So, these can be used for your purpose.

If you want specific additional properties for your requirement such as `testId`, `JiraId`, then you can use **test case level custom properties** and use them wherever required.